# Nested Tabs using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to draw nested tabs using Angularjs , but some tabs doesn't  point to its content

See my code

```
<tabs sortable="Visit.Organizations">
            <tab-buttons>
                <tab-button ng-repeat="organization in Visit.Organizations" sortable-item="$index" ng-click="SetCurrentTab(organization);">{{organization.Name}}</tab-button>
            </tab-buttons>
            <tab-contents>
                <tab-content ng-repeat="organization in Visit.Organizations">
                    <tabs sortable="organization.Departements">
                        <tab-buttons>
                            <tab-button ng-repeat="departement in organization.Departements" sortable-item="$index">{{departement.Name}}</tab-button>
                        </tab-buttons>
                        <tab-contents>
                            <tab-content ng-repeat="departement in organization.Departements">
                                {{departement.Name}}
                            </tab-content>
                        </tab-contents>
                    </tabs>
                </tab-content>
            </tab-contents>
        </tabs>
```

Only the first tab is visible and other tabs are not loading on selection.

any one help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this JSFiddle example.

https://jsfiddle.net/jccrosby/eRGT8/

It clearly defines the needed events for the tab controls and $scope variables.

```
$scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
    return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
}
```

Please check if you have defined these.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but maybe using organization as the same name within a nested ng-repeat may cause issues, I need to see more code of your controller to make a better conclusion though.